# How do I find the position of the first occurrence of a letter(from the alphabet) in a string?

Tags: python, string, letter

For example if the string is

```
s = "##catgiraffeapluscompscI"
```

How do I get the output to 2 since the first letter that occurs in this string is at position 2 (`c`)?

I also want this to be able to work for different strings as well (like a function) which may not have `c` as their first letter, so I don't want

```
s.find('c')
```

Comment: Can you specify what constitutes a letter?

Comment: A letter from the alphabet

Comment: Which alphabet?

Answer (score 7):

First finding the letter and then its index.

```
>>> s.find(next(filter(str.isalpha, s)))
2
```

Comment: I don't this answer didn't get much useful clicks. This is for me by far the cleanest code

Comment: this function doesn't handle the error condition where string `s` has no alphabet characters. If you run a string like `+-!` or ` ` or `12345` it will result in a StopIteration error

Comment: @Nathan Yeah, the question doesn't care (otherwise they would've specified what to do), so apparently I didn't either. You can get result `-1` for example by providing `next` with a default letter: `s.find(next(filter(str.isalpha, s), 'a'))` (although that's somewhat ugly).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to search for the first letter (a-z or A-Z by using the `re.I` flag), and if found, return the `start` value from the match object:

```
import re

def first_letter(s):
    m = re.search(r'[a-z]', s, re.I)
    if m is not None:
        return m.start()
    return -1

s = "##catgiraffeapluscompscI"
i = first_letter(s)
print(i)
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: getting this error when using your code                                                            Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    i = first_letter(s)  File "main.py", line 2, in first_letter    m = re.search(r'[a-z]', s, re.I)
NameError: name 're' is not defined


Comment: @JohnMaterum just realised the `import re` in my answer had bad formatting. You need to include that to bring in the regex (`re`) module. See my edit

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to import regex or other modules: the following uses standard library only, will ignore all non-alphabetic characters and give you the position of the first alphabetic character, using the isalpha() method.

```
foo = "##catgiraffeapluscompscI"

L = len(foo)

vivi = 0
for v in range(1,L):
    if foo[vivi].isalpha():
        print ("First alphabetic character " + foo[vivi] + " at position " + str(vivi))
        break
    vivi = vivi + 1
```

Output:

```
First alphabetic character c at position 2
```

Answer (score 1):

the top answer by kelly bundy only works for a happy path where there *is* a letter in the string. Otherwise `next()` ends up throwing a StopIteration error. This can simply be caught:

```
try:
  return s.find(next(filter(str.isalpha, s)))
except StopIteration:
  return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat a string as a list of characters, and iterate through it until you find a match. This while statement checks for the character, and if it does not exists it stops you falling off the end of the list.

```
s = "##catgiraffeapluscompscI"
index = 0
search_char = "c"

while (index != len(s)) and (s[index] != search_char):
    index += 1

if index == len(s):
    print("Character not in string")
else:
    print("Character is at position: ", index)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Nick's answer is, I think best. But regexes can be tough, and I'm not good with them, so I tend to stay away from them since in my hands they're pretty fragile.

So for what it's worth, here's a short way that doesn't use regexes:

```
import string
s = "##catgiraffeapluscompscI"
letters_found = [L for L in string.ascii_letters if L in s]
if letters_found:
    first_letter_position = min([s.find(L) for L in letters_found])
else:
    first_letter_position = -1
print(first_letter_position)
```

Basically, it makes a list of all the letters in your target (empty if there are none in the target); then for each letter that's present in the target, finds the first location; and takes the smallest of that.

But again, Nick's is better if you're comfortable with regexes.

Answer (score -2):

```
def find_index(input_string,input_value):
    return input_string.index(input_value))
answer = find_index("##catgiraffeapluscompscI", 'c')
print(answer)
```

Comment: This only works if you already know what the first letter will be.

Comment: You can use exception Handling to return None if sub-string is not found. Instead of Using seperate libraries, this is ideal option if you are only concerned with finding sub-string. But if you want to go with some advanced patterns matching based on Theory of Automata, then RE might be the area of concern.

Comment: It's not a matter of handling not-found; it's that it doesn't address the question. This answer returns the first location of the letter 'c'; the OP is asking for the first position of any letter.

For example, if s is set to "###snacktime", the correct value is 3 (the position of the 's'); the code posted here will return 6 (the position of the 'c').

Comment: Is it okay now? codingatty.  Same logic, OP was supposed to just write that in the body of function.

Comment: No; same problem. You're finding the first 'c', not the first letter.